# Can't see all git commits of branch from master

Tags: git, branch

I have the main master branch checked out in one working folder. I created another branch (let's call it "work"). I checked out the work branch in another working folder. In each working folder I made different changes. I've made commits to both branches. On the work branch I made a few rounds of changes, added a few tags, made my final commit. I pushed all the changes to origin.

Back in the master working copy I pulled the changes. In the master working copy I can do `git tag` and see the tags I made on the work branch. Note that I have not attempted any merge.

Now here is the problem. If, in my master working copy, I do: `git log work`, I don't see the last few commits made on the work branch.

Here's the list of commits shown while in the work branch working folder when I do `git log work`:

```
commit 6bc8c6e2e25541a204f2d83c3e9a7bbc5e0c43cf (HEAD -> work, tag: rel_6_6_4, origin/work)
commit c722d68bd81efabf5ab87dec433a8b7894ef2779 (tag: rel_6_6_3)
commit e4cedcb225af834c243545cccb3bcf44244ef5f6
commit a132dceff1ac86196d7012b8839e2731e775ea71 (tag: rel_6_6_2)
commit ac3759e8b87825e2c2d3c73c65fff9e033f28dcd
commit 1bedc55d00ac751651b33ca7eb82c4a09e046a8e
commit 428bfd95d9b195ebac61203ef4fd628a5e40a66d
commit f5a2fb8528bbdba76f117910bdc63b4bc68044cb
commit 5c51b13144e01fb190cf9f8840a978a3c51a6b76
commit 94f5dd9998fc977257742f4f29d1ab83fc4323b1
commit 17cb8e66db3bfc3c7fdbe5ebde7e41a1dbbd9614
```

The last commit shown in this list is where I created the work branch.

If I do `git status` in the work working folder I see:

```
On branch work
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/work'
```

If I run `git log work` in my master working folder, I see:

```
commit ac3759e8b87825e2c2d3c73c65fff9e033f28dcd (work)
commit 1bedc55d00ac751651b33ca7eb82c4a09e046a8e
commit 428bfd95d9b195ebac61203ef4fd628a5e40a66d
commit f5a2fb8528bbdba76f117910bdc63b4bc68044cb
commit 5c51b13144e01fb190cf9f8840a978a3c51a6b76
commit 94f5dd9998fc977257742f4f29d1ab83fc4323b1
commit 17cb8e66db3bfc3c7fdbe5ebde7e41a1dbbd9614
```

As you can see, the most recent 4 commits to the work branch do not appear in this list.

And doing `git status` in the master working folder shows:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

How do I get those last 4 commits to the work branch to appear from my working copy of the master branch?

One more clue to the puzzle. If I do `git log origin/work` from the master working folder, the list of commits looks like:

```
commit 6bc8c6e2e25541a204f2d83c3e9a7bbc5e0c43cf (tag: rel_6_6_4, origin/work)
commit c722d68bd81efabf5ab87dec433a8b7894ef2779 (tag: rel_6_6_3)
commit e4cedcb225af834c243545cccb3bcf44244ef5f6
commit a132dceff1ac86196d7012b8839e2731e775ea71 (tag: rel_6_6_2)
commit ac3759e8b87825e2c2d3c73c65fff9e033f28dcd (work)
commit 1bedc55d00ac751651b33ca7eb82c4a09e046a8e
commit 428bfd95d9b195ebac61203ef4fd628a5e40a66d
commit f5a2fb8528bbdba76f117910bdc63b4bc68044cb
commit 5c51b13144e01fb190cf9f8840a978a3c51a6b76
commit 94f5dd9998fc977257742f4f29d1ab83fc4323b1
commit 17cb8e66db3bfc3c7fdbe5ebde7e41a1dbbd9614
```

How do I get `(work)` to move to that first commit?

If more info is needed, let me know so I can add it to the question.

Comment: Are you pushing both to the same remote? `git remote -v`

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon Yes, the output of `git remove -v` in both working folders is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're master folder is tracking master, not work. You need to do `git log origin/work`

Edit:
You need to update the work branch inside your master working folder

```
git checkout work
git merge origin/work
git log work
```

To go back to master

```
git checkout master
```

Shortcut to above command:
`git push . origin/work:work`

Comment: Then why can I see any of the changes made on the work branch from the master working folder?

Comment: It sounds like your master working folder also has a work branch. That's why `git log work` shows older commits. You need to checkout that branch and update it. Did you try `git log origin/work` in the master working folder?

Comment: I just updated the question with the output of `git log origin/work` from the master working folder. That seems to offer a clue. But I don't know git well enough.

Comment: Do you want the contents of origin/work to be merged to the master working folder or update the work branch in the master working folder? If you do a `git branch` in your master working directory I expect to see both master and work.

Comment: `git branch` shows both "master" and "work" in both working folders (of course the asterisk points to the appropriate one in each). I don't really want to do a merge. I just want to be able to see all changes to the work branch from my master working folder by doing `git log work`. I don't know why I can see most but not the last few.

Comment: See answer above

Comment: And to fast-forward your local branch, without switching branches first, you can do `git push . origin/work:work`

Comment: @knittl I tried that in my work branch working folder and it simply replied "Everything up-to-date".

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon Why? I don't want to push master to the work branch.

Comment: That will update your "work" branch inside your master working folder. It will not alter the "master" branch.

Comment: That fixed it. I need time to understand it but it worked. If you can update your answer with just that `git push . origin/work:work` needing to be run in my master working folder, I can accept it. Or @knittl should post that as an answer since it was their comment to begin with.